# Why performSelector:withObject: methods can only take id?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, ios, pointers

In Objective-C, all methods performing selectors are like:

```
 - performSelector:withObject:
 - makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:
 - performSelectorInBackground:withObject:
```

And can only take id (Pointer) objects in parameter ? Do you know why ? is that something inherited from C, and working with threads we need to have a pointer ?

---

**Edit:** And in Objective-C we can not create pointer directly. If I want to do something like below with a pointer, is this working or not ?? (I know about the NSNumber and NSValue classes, but I just want to understand how does it work)

```
int i = 5;
int *pointer_i = &i;
[self performSelector:mySelector withObject:pointer_i];
```

Comment: Ah!! You can say it takes one argument of type void *. But i am still to understand your question here.

Comment: @Praveen S Every `id` is a pointer, but not every `void *` are `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast `withObject:(id)pointer_i` but this is a **bad idea**.
In this particular instance, the argument to the `withObject:` is `retain`ed.  If you pass in an `int *` where the method is expecting an `id`, your program will crash because it is trying to `retain` an `int`!

Comment: Ok thank you! I just saw that if I create an NSNumber with my int, and in my function I try to display it, it is displaying a weird number. NSLog(@"My number: %i", i); prints: 1073752700 it's the pointer address ?

Comment: You're using a format specifier `%i` for an `int`.  You should either switch to using the `%@` object description specifier or use `[i intValue]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can only give pointer as arguments, so objective-c objects. If you want to use an integer, try this:

```
int i;
[self performSelector:@selector(mySelector:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
```

Comment: Yes I know that (I updated my question about pointers in Objective-C).

Comment: Then what is the problem further? Just use an NSNumber instead of a direct int. int is a primitive, and does not use a pointer, whereas NSNumber is an object which can contain any type of primitive number, and is a pointer.

Comment: Hm, then you should be able to use that in Objective-c too, i thought. Never heard of it though. When i had this problem myself, all hints pointed towards using NSNumber. I'll check if i can find anything on int pointers.

Comment: The `id` type means that these methods can take any kind of object. It does NOT mean that you can pass them any old pointer type that you feel like.

Comment: so an id type is a specific type of pointer in Objective-c? That would explain the difference with C Ludovic named.

Comment: Yes. `id` is a pointer to any *object* (instance of an Obj-C class). See the *id* section here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html

Answer (score 1):

Because id is a pointer to any kind of object. So you don't need to know what type of Object you got (NSString, NSArray). An id can point to anything.

Comment: So, I assume my edit with the int pointer is working ? Xcode says "incompatible pointer type 'int *' to parameter 'id'". We know that 'id' is 'void *', so I can cast my pointer in 'id" and it will work ?

Comment: Passing an arbitrary pointer (like an int *) to an interface that is expecting an object pointer is asking for trouble. Even if it appears to "work" now, it's incorrect, and could easily break in a subsequent OS revision.

Comment: I would rephrase that to say that `id` is a pointer to any subclass of `NSObject`, as opposed to "a pointer to any kind of object". You definitely can't think of `id` as a `void*`. You can't do what the OP tried to do and pass a `int *` (well, you can get around it and do it, but it's not smart at all)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can pass in any single object (which itself could be an array or a dictionary, if you need that kind of flexibility, but you need to be able to pass that inside the function you call, of course.

The reason I'm leaving this answer though, is to mention a trap that has caused me hours of frustration when using this.  If you leave out the colon after the selector name, the app will compile but it will crash at run time.

To use a previous example

```
[self performSelector:@selector(mySelector:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
```

"mySelector:" needs the colon.

Okay, maybe this is a little thing, and obvious to hard core coders, but it took me a lot of time to debug this.  If you code is crashing and the object you are passing is valid, then probably the selector is not.